# How do I access site.project.rails (running on host) from VMWare fusion?

Tags: mac-osx, ruby-on-rails, phusion-passenger, vmware-fusion

I have a rails app setup and running on my snow leopard MacBook - the app is being served by Passenger. As part of the setup they had me add entries for 127.0.0.1 site.project.rails in my hosts file so I could reach the site from site.project.rails

I can't for the life of me figure out how to get the app show up in VMWare. I have XP setup and browse to http://site.project.rails and I can't get it to show up.

I setup a basic rails app, being served at localhost:3000 by webrick, I can get that to load by visiting my hosts ip (http://192.168.1.1:3000/). I added the same hosts I added on my Mac to Windows.

I also Bridged the network under settings for the VM. What am I missing?

Comment: What happens when you try to ping site.project.rails from the VM?  Do you get an IP address or does it not resolve the host?

Answer (score 0):

/etc/hosts is local to that machine only, which would be on the macbook.

Try using the IP address of the macbook on the vmware client

Comment: I edited the hosts file in Windows too. I won't reach the app I wan't if I hit the host IP - the app runs at the location site.project.rails (added vhosts and entries to /etc/hosts to support this)

Comment: The instructions you followed assumed you access the site from the same machine running the site.  Since this is not the case, either put the Macbook's IP address in /etc/hosts (and the windows version of that file) or use the IP address.